# How can I verify success status of a thread in PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading

I have a PHP code that calls about 100 threads simultaneously each thread fetches one HTML page and parse it using **Simple HTML DOM Parser** for certain information.

Here is the code

```
    //some code, including a loop to generate counter for thread
    $thread[$counter] = new fetch($link);
    $thread[$counter]->start();

    foreach($thread as $t){
        if($t->join()){
            //do something
        }//if
    }//foreach
```

Here is the code that is executed for each thread.

```
public function run(){
    $content = file_get_html("http:blahblabha");

    foreach($content->find('something') as $TL)
        $this->var = $TL->xmltext;
    }//run
```

However, though I can verify that threads complete using `join()` method, but out of 100 threads, it returns data of about 95 of them and 5 of the complete without successful fetch and parsing of data.

My code uses a class that extends Thread.

Comment: You'd have to check the thread's status - e.g. if they fail to do the http fetch, they should make a note of that somewhere.

Comment: I use "file_get_html" to fetch page. Any clue for that? Does file_get_html return true or false on success?

Comment: @baldrs why downvote? Thread is always a key for multithreading. I have PHP in title too. I modify the question. Can you upvote?

Comment: @Espanta what is file_get_html? Which library provides it?

Comment: @baldrs PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser provides fetch and parsing of HTML file in PHP.

Comment: @Espanta specify this in question. Also that you use pthreads extension as well.

Comment: -1 for not providing code. You also asked similar question before. You don't check whether a thread is done using `join()`, you synchronize with it and check whether it `isRunning()`.

Comment: @Espanta please improve your question according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @N.B. Earlier question was about completion of all running 100 threads for which I provided code. However, here I am willing to check if every thread has successfully completed or not. These two are different. I don't think providing code here does make any change in the solution. It is a general question about pthread in PHP. If you think bringing code makes positive, I do.

Comment: @Espanta there are no telepathy-enabled people, you know. Code is necessary to help with your question.

Comment: The code makes all the difference. We can debate whether or not it matters, bur you're the one asking and you're the one not getting answers. It depends whether you're using `Thread` or if you're using `Stackable` with `Worker`. They have different ways of checking whether something is working or not. You synchronize with the thread and check a property (`$this->is_working` or similar`. If true - it is busy, if not - it is done. In case of a Thread, once done you can see it's finished. With Worker it's not the case. You have all of this in pthreads examples.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll attempt to steer you in the right direction.

From what I know about posix threads, the `pthread_join()` suspends the calling context until the referenced thread terminates. Once that's done, any resources allocated to that thread are freed - anyone with better understanding, please correct me here.

Now, that's opposite of what you want. What you want, also correct me if I'm wrong, is that you want to know whether ALL the threads are finished or not and you don't want to block for each of the 100 - that makes everything synchronous.

What you might want implies an evented system of a sort. That means your code looks like this:

```
 fire up 100 threads
 do work in each thread
 when all 100 are done, consider the processing finished
```

If I were you, I'd create 100 threads + 1 more. That 1 extra would be the thread that fires up the threads and collects their data once they finish working. That 1, let's call it `Work sink`, would be the thread that your main context speaks to, and once that thread is done - your 100 threads have finished the work. Now, from my limited knowledge, you don't join a thread to check its status. You can synchronize with it and check a status of a member which can tell you whether it's still working or not.

As for *how* to code all this, from what I see on the official git repo and on php.net - there are many examples that show how to synchronize with a thread and check its execution status. You can also share objects that descend from `Threaded` between threads, which makes it possible to create Work Sink thread which creates the other 100, or it can accept the other 100 threads via constructor. You have many options here, from using thread pool that comes with pthreads to coding your own etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I think you response is for my earlier question about completion which I have solved by as you mentioned manual coding. In this stage, I need some control weather a thread successfully completed or failed and completed. I know similar concept of complete/success/fail in jQuery when we use Ajax. However, I have no idea if this concept matches here or not.